# Double burnination request: exam review

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

[exam](/questions/tagged/exam) and on Stack Overflow seems to be mostly used to indicate that the OP is either cheating on their exam by asking us to do their work for them or, less nefariously, studying for an exam. Either way, it's a useless meta tag. (it's also occasionally used to indicate the OP is writing an exam system, in which case it's instead just a useless keyword that no one would be searching for.)

[review](/questions/tagged/review) is somewhat related in that it's often combined with [exam](/questions/tagged/exam) to indicate that OP is reviewing material before an exam. It's also occasionally used to discuss the review processes at various app stores or elsewhere, although IMO it doesn't add much to the questions (if they're even on-topic for SO, which is arguable.)

Can we burninate both of these?

Answer (score 7):

I say yes, and also make sure to flag/vote to close questions or if they are legitimate questions, make sure to edit for other content (fix up grammar, format code, etc).

In the case of the [exam](/questions/tagged/exam) tag, I'd look for NARQ flags/closures.

For the [review](/questions/tagged/review) I'd look for Off Topic flags/closures.

Be reminded that those two reasons aren't the *only* reasons to close a question, just probably the primary reasons.